# Bug in object comparison in pandas

Tags: pandas

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'encoded': [1, 25, 10, 40, 50, 4, 5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['encoded'] = df['encoded'].astype(str)
query_filters = "encoded > '20'"
print(df.query(query_filters, engine='python'))
```

What is the reason filtering doesn't work in above? I understand that if I don't do type conversion and compare as int it will work, but, why it is not working in above. I am getting it as object type from DB so want to avoid type conversion.

Comment: In a string compare `'4' > '20'`